# MongoDB service failing to start after db move

Tags: mongodb

My MongoDB install on Amazon EC2 ran out of disk space, so I created a new EBS volume, shut down the MongoDB service cleanly, copied the DB files to the new volume, remounted in the same position as the old partition and tried to restart the service, but I'm getting this error:

```
Sat Jun  9 10:03:30 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=24466 port=27017 dbpath=/db/mongo 64-bit host=ip-10-234-7-0
Sat Jun  9 10:03:30 [initandlisten] db version v2.0.5, pdfile version 4.5
Sat Jun  9 10:03:30 [initandlisten] git version: 1bb4de4630302fad8af53824ca4f627db490b753
Sat Jun  9 10:03:30 [initandlisten] build info: Linux ip-10-110-9-236 2.6.21.7-2.ec2.v1.2.fc8xen #1 SMP Fri Nov 20 17:48:28 EST 2009 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_41
Sat Jun  9 10:03:30 [initandlisten] options: { config: "/etc/mongodb.conf", dbpath: "/succeed/db/mongo", logappend: "true", logpath: "/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log" }
Sat Jun  9 10:03:30 [initandlisten] journal dir=/db/mongo/journal
Sat Jun  9 10:03:30 [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
Sat Jun  9 10:03:30 [initandlisten] warning couldn't write to / rename file /db/mongo/journal/prealloc.0
Sat Jun  9 10:03:30 [initandlisten] couldn't open /db/mongo/MyDB_Mongo.ns errno:1 Operation not permitted
Sat Jun  9 10:03:30 [initandlisten] error couldn't open file /db/mongo/MyDB_Mongo.ns terminating
Sat Jun  9 10:03:30 dbexit: 
Sat Jun  9 10:03:30 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
Sat Jun  9 10:03:30 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
Sat Jun  9 10:03:30 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
Sat Jun  9 10:03:30 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
Sat Jun  9 10:03:30 [initandlisten] shutdown: lock for final commit...
Sat Jun  9 10:03:30 [initandlisten] shutdown: final commit...
Sat Jun  9 10:03:30 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
Sat Jun  9 10:03:30 [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
Sat Jun  9 10:03:30 [initandlisten] journalCleanup...
Sat Jun  9 10:03:30 [initandlisten] removeJournalFiles
Sat Jun  9 10:03:30 [initandlisten] shutdown: removing fs lock...
Sat Jun  9 10:03:30 dbexit: really exiting now
```

Directory has appropriate permissions for the mongodb user.  Can anyone shed any light on why this is not starting?  I can start manually as root using the config

I should mention that doing this works:

```
$ sudo su mongodb
$ mongod --config /etc/mongodb.conf &
```

And I'm using MongoDB 2.0.5 from the 10-gen apt repositories.

Comment: could you check ls -l on /db and /db/mongo?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused by non-sufficient privileges for the mongodb user.Restarting the mongodb service after fixing the permissions should do the trick.

Comment: Actually, after speaking to 10-gen, the problem stems from the Ubuntu service that comes in the mongodb package from the Ubuntu apt repository.  I switched from the Ubuntu repo to the 10-gen repo and hadn't recognised that the service was still the Ubuntu one.  I'm not finding the Ubuntu service script easy to follow though.